# How to find data between commas with a special phrases to anchor

Tags: python, regex

I have html string that:

```
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
   prod155920017Matrix = new Array();
   prod155920017Matrix[0] = new Array();
   prod155920017Matrix[1] = new Array();
   prod155920017Matrix[2] = new Array();
   prod155920017Matrix[3] = new Array();
   prod155920017Matrix[4] = new Array();
   prod155920017Matrix[5] = new Array();
   prod155920017Matrix[6] = new Array();
   prod155920017Matrix[7] = new Array();
   prod155920017Matrix[8] = new Array();
   prod155920017Matrix[9] = new Array();
   prod155920017Matrix[0][0] = new product('0','prod155920017','sku143650081','36.0B/6.0B','BLACK','Joni Snake-Print Thong Sandal',false,0,'',8,'3','/category/images/prod_stock1.gif',new Array(),'','false',9999,'null');
   prod155920017Matrix[0][0].vendorRestrictedDates[0] = '20130903';
   prod155920017Matrix[0][0].vendorRestrictedDates[1] = '20131129';
   prod155920017Matrix[0][0].vendorRestrictedDates[2] = '20130902';
   prod155920017Matrix[0][0].vendorRestrictedDates[3] = '20130101';
   prod155920017Matrix[0][0].vendorRestrictedDates[4] = '20121225';
   prod155920017Matrix[0][0].vendorRestrictedDates[5] = '20130528';
   prod155920017Matrix[0][0].vendorRestrictedDates[6] = '20140102';
   prod155920017Matrix[0][0].vendorRestrictedDates[7] = '20140101';
   prod155920017Matrix[0][0].vendorRestrictedDates[8] = '20131128';
   prod155920017Matrix[0][0].vendorRestrictedDates[9] = '20131226';
   prod155920017Matrix[0][0].vendorRestrictedDates[10] = '20121226';
   prod155920017Matrix[0][0].vendorRestrictedDates[11] = '20130527';
   prod155920017Matrix[0][0].vendorRestrictedDates[12] = '20130705';
   prod155920017Matrix[0][0].vendorRestrictedDates[13] = '20131225';
   prod155920017Matrix[0][0].vendorRestrictedDates[14] = '20130102';
   prod155920017Matrix[0][0].vendorRestrictedDates[15] = '20130704';


   prod155920017Matrix[0][0].storeFulfillStatus = 'false';
   prod155920017Matrix[1][0] = new product('0','prod155920017','sku143650082','36.5B/6.5B','BLACK','Joni Snake-Print Thong Sandal',false,0,'',10,'3','/category/images/prod_stock1.gif',new Array(),'','false',9999,'null');   
</SCRIPT>
```

I try to use this regex: `new product(\([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)` to get data: '36.0B/6.0B','BLACK', from **script** tag. But i can't.
Please help me get them.
Thanks all very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\'\d{2}\.\d[A-Z]\/\d\.\d[A-Z]\',\'[\w]+\'
```

This should get you the expected result.
Since regex can only do pattern matching, you cannot 'add characters' like ( and ) around the result strings using regex, you will have to do that using python.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is in the wrong spot:

```
new product\(([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)
```

Comment: If you fix that and still have problems, post your Python code.

Comment: @ John Kugelman: thanks you. With your regex I give result: [("'0'",
"'prod154770007'",
"'sku142930041'",
"'35.0B/5.0B'",
"'PINK'"),
("'0'",
"'prod154770007'",
"'sku142930042'",
"'35.5B/5.5B'",
"'PINK'")]. But i want [("'35.0B/5.0B'",
"'PINK'"),
("'35.5B/5.5B'",
"'PINK'")].Please help me.